# Prove the series expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Prove that
$$(1+x)^\frac{1}{x}=e-\frac{e}{2}x+\frac{11e}{24}x^2-\frac{7e}{16}x^3....$$
where e is exponenial ,
can any one give a proof...I tried with series expansion i could not get it.

Comment: When $x\to 0$, I assume?

Comment: Have you tried using that $(1+x)^\frac{1}{x} = e^\frac{log(1+x)}{x}$, and then composing the series of $e^x$ and $log(1+x)$? You only need the first terms, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** you can use Taylor expansions, indeed.
$$\ln(1+x) = x-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + o(x^3)$$
when $x \to 0$; and $e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^3)$. Now, $$(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}} = e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x)},$$
so composing the above two series will give you what you seek.

Comment: Poetic, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also compute $f^{\prime}(x)$. As $f(x)=\exp(\frac{\log(1+x)}{x})$, you get
$$f^{\prime}(x)=\frac{\frac{x}{1+x}-\log(1+x)}{x^2}f(x)=\frac{\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n-1}x^n-\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}}{x^2} f(x)$$

Thus:

$$f^{\prime}(x)=(\sum_{n\geq 2}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n-1}{n}x^{n-2})f(x)=(\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{k+1}{k+2}x^k)f(x)$$
and putting $f(x)=\sum_{m\geq 0} a_m x^m$, we get
$$(m+1)a_{m+1}=\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^{k+1}\frac{k+1}{k+2}a_{m-k}$$
and using $a_0=e$, it is now easy to compute the $a_m$.